# Adding and removing an element class that sorts a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that can be sorted through an icon

The icon sorts asc and desc

The code below was obtained through inspect elements

```
<th id="thCliente" class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 336.984px;" aria-sort="descending" aria-label="Cliente: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Cliente</th>
```

I need that when loading the page it is always in sorting_asc - ascending sorting

How can I perform this operation using javascript and/or jquery?

image of the icon that orders

[image: image of the icon that orders]

code that appears in inspect elements

[image: code that appears in inspect elements]

attempt

```
$("#thCliente").removeClass().addClass("sorting_asc:before")
```

Table Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="dataTables_scroll">
      <div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px; width: 100%;">
         <div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 1119px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <table class="table table-sm font-size-12 table-striped nowrap dataTable no-footer" role="grid" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 1119px;">
               <thead>
                  <tr role="row">
                     <th style="font: small-caption; width: 18.1406px;" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="
                        : Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="Checando(this)" title="Marcar Todos">
                     </th>
                     <th title="Desautorizar" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 11.4688px;" aria-label="D: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">D</th>
                     <th id="thCliente" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 336.984px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Cliente: Ordenar colunas de forma descendente">Cliente</th>
                     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103.438px;" aria-label="Serviço: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Serviço</th>
                     <th title="Relatório de Faturamento" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 48.5469px;" aria-label="Rel. Fat.: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Rel. Fat.</th>
                     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 80.9062px;" aria-label="Competência: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Competência</th>
                     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 74.0625px;" aria-label="Vencimento: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Vencimento</th>
                     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50.5312px;" aria-label="Entrada: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Entrada</th>
                     <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 37.7656px;" aria-label="Saída: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Saída</th>
                     <th title="Data da Autorização" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 57.375px;" aria-label="Data Aut.: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Data Aut.</th>
                     <th title="Lançamento Automático" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 27.0156px;" aria-label="Aut.: Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente">Aut.</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; max-height: 50vh; width: 100%;">
         <table id="basic-datatable" class="table table-sm font-size-12 table-striped nowrap dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="basic-datatable_info" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
               <tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
                  <th style="font: small-caption; width: 18.1406px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="Checando(this)" title="Marcar Todos">
                     </div>
                  </th>
                  <th title="Desautorizar" class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 11.4688px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">D</div>
                  </th>
                  <th id="thCliente" class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 336.984px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Cliente</div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103.438px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Serviço</div>
                  </th>
                  <th title="Relatório de Faturamento" class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 48.5469px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Rel. Fat.</div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 80.9062px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Competência</div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 74.0625px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Vencimento</div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50.5312px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Entrada</div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 37.7656px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Saída</div>
                  </th>
                  <th title="Data da Autorização" class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 57.375px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Data Aut.</div>
                  </th>
                  <th title="Lançamento Automático" class="sorting" aria-controls="basic-datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 27.0156px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                     <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">Aut.</div>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd wager that changing the class won't actually sort the table. How are you creating the table?

Comment: the table has pre-set template definitions, but I feed it with the data that is in my database using Classic ASP

Comment: If necessary, I can contribute codes and images.

Comment: One of those pre-set template definitions will almost certainly be a sort order.

Comment: I understand, but I use this same table in several areas of my system, this case is one in particular that orders through a select with a certain value and when accessing the page

Comment: If you provide the code that creates the table, it'll at least provide a frame of reference

Comment: table information added

Comment: `sorting_asc:before` what kind of className is that?

Comment: You're using the [dataTable](https://datatables.net/) plugin?

Comment: I am yes @zer00ne

Comment: @DavidCustódio see [options](https://datatables.net/manual/options)

Answer (score 2):

I'm half-guessing here based on the limited information. But in most cases, the class doesn't actually control the sort order (usually it's the other way around).

In the vast majority of cases, there'll be a click event on the element that controls the sort order, so what you could do (if there isn't a property you can directly set when creating the table) is something like this:

```
$('#thCliente').click();
```

Assuming that element is indeed the one that controls the sort order.

Although to clear up your misconception as to how to switch the class:

```
$('#thCliente').toggleClass('sorting_asc sorting_desc');
```

Will toggle the ascending and descending classes. But it would not switch any of the corresponding `aria` properties.